# What is maximum likelihood PCA?

Tags: pca, maximum-likelihood, chemometrics

There are many papers on this topic, such as [this one](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/(SICI)1099-128X(199707)11:4%3C339::AID-CEM476%3E3.0.CO;2-L/abstract) ([pdf](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.112.5325&rep=rep1&type=pdf)). However, I could not find out what exactly maximum likelihood PCA is, how it is applied and for which purpose.

Can anyone explain it?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the context in which you read this sentence? Or perhaps give a link to one of the papers. Are you asking about probabilistic PCA (PPCA)?

Comment: @amoeba for example this paper http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/(SICI)1099-128X(199707)11:4%3C339::AID-CEM476%3E3.0.CO;2-L/abstract

Comment: The abstract of the paper you cite looks pretty specific about what it does. Do you want to elaborate on your question by specifying which bits you understand and which not?

Comment: @mdewey I am not searching for specific answer. I want to know what it does etc ... I am not looking to find specific algorithm inside it,

Answer (score 1):

Possibly this article (which is [online readable](http://eprints.soton.ac.uk/263302/1/mieke.pdf)) is also helpful. In the following the abstract:

> Abstract
> The maximum likelihood PCA (MLPCA) method has been devised in
> chemometrics as a generalization of the well-known PCA method in order
> to derive consistent estimators in the presence of errors with known
> error distribution. For similar reasons, the total least squares (TLS)
> method has been generalized in the ﬁeld of computational mathematics
> and engineering to maintain consistency of the parameter estimates in
> linear models with measurement errors of known distribution. The basic
> motivation for TLS is the following. Let a set of multi-dimensional
> data points (vectors) be given. How can one obtain a linear model that
> explains these data? The idea is to modify all data points in such a
> way that some norm of the modiﬁcation is minimized subject to the
> constraint that the modiﬁed vectors satisfy a linear relation.
> Although the name “total least squares” appeared in the literature
> only 25 years ago, this method of ﬁtting is certainly not new and has
> a long history in the statistical literature, where the method is
> known as “orthogonal regression”, “errors-in-variables regression” or
> “measurement error modeling”.
>
> The purpose of this paper is to explore
> the tight equivalences between MLPCA and element-wise weighted TLS
> (EW-TLS). Despite their seemingly different problem formulation, it is
> shown that both methods can be reduced to the same mathematical kernel
> problem, i.e. ﬁnding the closest (in a certain sense) weighted low
> rank matrix approximation where the weight is derived from the
> distribution of the errors in the data. Different solution approaches,
> as used in MLPCA and EW-TLS, are discussed. In particular, we will
> discuss the weighted low rank approximation (WLRA), the MLPCA, the
> EW-TLS and the generalized TLS (GTLS) problems. These four approaches
> tackle an equivalent weighted low rank approximation problem, but
> different algorithms are used to come up with the best approximation
> matrix. We will compare their computation times on chemical data and
> discuss their convergence behavior.
>
> © 2004 Elsevier B.V. All rights reserved.
> Keywords: TLS; MLPCA; Rank reduction; Measurement errors